# How to make apache let me define the body of a "200 OK" response with a Location header?

Tags: apache, http, cgi, httpd.conf

Here is what I have in a cgi-bin directory:

```
cgi-bin> cat test1
#!/bin/sh
echo "Status: 200 OK"
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo
echo "Hello world 1"

cgi-bin> cat test2
#!/bin/sh
echo "Status: 200 OK"
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo "Location: /cgi-bin/test1"
echo
echo "Hello world 2"

cgi-bin> cat test3
#!/bin/sh
echo "Status: 201 Created"
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo "Location: /cgi-bin/test1"
echo
echo "Hello world 3"
```

And here is what I get when I do a GET against each one:

```
cgi-bin> curl -i https://localhost/cgi-bin/test1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 Nov 2019 15:56:43 GMT
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello world 1

cgi-bin> curl -i https://localhost/cgi-bin/test2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 Nov 2019 15:56:44 GMT
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello world 1

cgi-bin> curl -i https://localhost/cgi-bin/test3
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Wed, 20 Nov 2019 15:56:45 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: /cgi-bin/test1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello world 3
```

Notice that /cgi-bin/test2 ignores the "Hello world 2" body that shell script prints, and instead displays the output of `test1`. How can I make it use "Hello world 2" as its response, without changing the Status or Location headers?

Edit: updated curl examples to include HTTP headers. Just noticed /cgi-bin/test2 does not include the Location header in the response either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as expected for me:

```
[root@pe610 cgi-bin]# curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/test2
Hello world 1
[root@pe610 cgi-bin]# curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/test1
Hello world 1
[root@pe610 cgi-bin]# apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov  5 2018 01:47:09
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Comment: I should also note that the CGI specification indicates that Apache should process the Location redirect internally if it's a local header. In other words, Location headers and CGI can have odd behaviors that aren't sent to the client. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-6.2.2

Comment: Thanks! So basically, the behavior I'm seeing is actually correct, and I should not try to change it.

Answer (score 0):

> The Location response header indicates the URL to redirect a page to.
>   It only provides a meaning when served with a 3xx (redirection) or 201
>   (created) status response.

In your case, you send a 200 with a Location, which is not compliant. Curl probably assumes it's a 201, so here's what's applied:

> The HTTP 201 Created success status response code indicates that the
>   request has succeeded and has led to the creation of a resource. The
>   new resource is effectively created before this response is sent back
>   and the new resource is returned in the body of the message, its
>   location being either the URL of the request, or the content of the
>   Location header.

Since you're sending conflicting headers, there's no way you can ask Curl to handle that in a meaningful manner.

Out of curiosity, why would you even want to do that? The resource should either be a 200, 201 or redirect, not a mix of them. If you want to use the Location header for something else, then you'll need to send a custom header like `my-custom-location` and treat it accordingly.

Comment: **RE: why would you even want to do that?**

This is required by a REST protocol, in 1 unusual case, that I'm implementing.

**RE: you send a 200 with a Location, which is not compliant.**

I see that's not the *recommended* way to use the Location header, but I've never found anything (e.g. in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7231.txt) that says it's actually *wrong*?

It appears apache is doing this, not curl. So I'm hoping there's some way to configure apache differently *or* convince the owners of this REST protocol this just isn't a correct thing to do.

Comment: What do you see if you use the `-I` option with curl? You'll be able to see what Apache actually sent and if it's been manipulating your headers further.

Comment: Apparently I can't use carriage returns in comments... `cgi-bin> curl -I https://localhost/cgi-bin/test2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 Nov 2019 15:45:26 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/plain`

Comment: Thanks, this confirms what Patrick answered, the redirect has been handled beforehand as the final headers don't have the `Location` anymore